# Works with QGridLayout not with QVBoxLayout

Tags: user-interface, layout, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, os, time

class SetName(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.show()
        toplayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setWindowTitle('Personal Info')
        self.form_layout = QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.form_layout)
        self.line_edit_param = QLineEdit(self)

        self.line_edit_param.setPlaceholderText("Write Here")
        self.form_layout.addRow('Write Name', self.line_edit_param)      
        toplayout.addLayout(self.form_layout)
        self.setFocus()

class LearnApp(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("LearnApp")

        self.active = False

        close_button = QPushButton("Close")
        close_button.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.check_button = QPushButton("Check")
        self.check_button.clicked.connect(self.set_data)        
        self.tr = QTextEdit()
        self.tr.setReadOnly(True)
        # layout
        layout = QHBoxLayout()        
        #layout.addWidget(self.button3)
        sub_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        sub_layout.addWidget(self.check_button)
        sub_layout.addWidget(close_button)
        layout.addLayout(sub_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.tr)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setFocus()

    def set_data(self):
        print "in set_data"
        SetName()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = LearnApp()
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

This is the code I'm trying. If edit it with `toplayout = QGridLayout()`, program works fine but with `toplayout = QVBoxLayout()`, it gives message `QLayout::addChildLayout: layout "" already has a parent`and just flashes the new window. What could be the problem? How should I tackle this? I wanna use `QVBoxLayout` instead of `QGridLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the new window disappears straight away because you don't store a reference to it. You need to store a reference to the instance in your `LearnApp` class, or parent it to another Qt object outside of `set_data()` if you want it to stick around.

The error message regarding the layouts is not occurring because of your choice of layouts, but because you are calling

```
self.setLayout(self.form_layout)
```

and then

```
toplayout.addLayout(self.form_layout)
```

The first call assigns the layout to the instance of `SetName`, but in doing so also makes the instance the parent of `self.form_layout`. The second call is trying to add the same layout to `toplayout` and set it as the parent, but Qt sees that `self.form_layout` already has a parent (i.e. is being used elsewhere). This is what the error message is trying to tell you.

I suspect that instead of `self.setLayout(self.form_layout)`, you intended to write something like

```
self.setLayout(toplayout)
```

Comment: Hey thanks... that error is gone when I made the changes you suggested but still 'Personal Info' window just flashes. Comes and goes away! Why this is happening?

Comment: How did you store the reference? You need to make sure you assign it as a member of the class with something like `self.setname = SetName()`. If you just store it in a local variable (i.e. `setname = SetName()`) it will be deleted as soon as `set_data()` returns.